# QMessage while waiting for a ping command response

Tags: c++, qt, ping, qmessagebox

I'm doing a ping to an IP address, and I want to show into a QMessageBox that a ping operation is going on. After that, if a response is received or one second timeout happens, I want to close the QMessageBox.

Code:

```
int status;
QByteArray command;
QMessageBox myBox(QMessageBox::Information, QString("Info"), QString("Checking connection"), QMessageBox::NoButton, this);

command.append("ping -w 1 172.22.1.1");
status=system(command);
myBox.setStandardButtons(0);
myBox.exec();
if (0==status){ // Response received
    // Some stuff here...
    myeBox.setVisible(false);
}
else { // Timeout
    // Some other stuff here...
    myBox.setVisible(false);
}
```

My guess is that I may need to use threads for this task, but since I am a Qt newbie maybe the problem is anywhere else.

EDIT:
As @atamanroman suggested I've tried to use QProcess, using signal void QProcess::finished ( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus ) [signal] as told in Qt reference:

```
private:
QProcess *process;
//...

      QMessageBox myBox(QMessageBox::Information, QString("Info"), QString("Checking connection"), QMessageBox::NoButton, this);
    QObject::connect(&process, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), &myBox, SLOT(close()));
    command.append("ping -w 1 172.22.1.1");
    process.start(comdand);
        myBox.setStandardButtons(0);
        myBox.exec();
```

And it's not working. myBox is never closed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `QProcess` (start ping.exe and parse output) or `QTcpSocket` (do the ping yourself) instead of `system()` because they are part of Qt and can signal you when the ping has finished. Connect to that signal in order to hide your `QMessageBox`.

Comment: Where the message box (or, better, QProgressDialog) should be a class member instead of being created locally on the stack and closed in the slots QProcess::finished() and ::error() are connected to.

Answer (score 0):

In your edit:
First:

```
QProcess *process; // This is a pointer, you don't need to add "&" in connect
                   // You should have called "process = new QProcess" before...
QMessageBox myBox; // This is an object, you need to add the "&" to connect;
```

We take out the first &

```
QObject::connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), &myBox, SLOT(close()));
```

second:
Using Linux ping will never stop, then you will never have the finished signal. You can provide ping some parameters like count or time to wait. Or start a timer to stop the process.

third:
You need to match the parameters between signals and slots to avoid warnings, etc.
I sugest you to create a local SLOT "processfinished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)" and then you call to myBox.Close(), but "myBox" must be from class to have reference to this after end the method where you call it.